# Google Maps Markers Wont Show Up

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
                    <script type="text/javascript">

                    function initMap() {
                        // Map
                        var mapOptions = {
                            zoom: 4,
                            center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.000000,-40.000000),
                            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                            draggable: false,
                            scrollwheel: false,
                            disableDefaultUI: true,
                            disableDoubleClickZoom: true
                        }
                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

                        // Markers
                        var madrid = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: google.maps.LatLng(40.412154, -3.704301),
                            map: map,
                            title: 'Madrid'
                        });

                        madrid.setMap(map);
                    }
                </script>
```

I am trying to put some markers on the map of certain cities. I can not seem to make the makers apear. I have looked through several forums, and tried everything.

I hope this is enough information. I am still very new to stack overflow, so If I did this wrong, please let me know how to post a question more clearly.

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `new` keyword for position parameter while creating marker, please check the below code, it should work.

```
function initMap() {

    // Map
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.000000, -40.000000),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        draggable: false,
        scrollwheel: false,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        disableDoubleClickZoom: true
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    // Markers
    var madrid = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.412154, -3.704301),
        map: map,
        title: 'Madrid'
    });

    madrid.setMap(map);
}
```

Comment: It was tricky to find the only change in your code. In case you've wandering which line changed: `position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.412154, -3.704301),`

Comment: set Zoom level to 3 if you still don't see after adding new .